# Fast-paced Android strategy/empire management game that is completely playable offline

Tags: android, game, offline

I'm leaving on vacation to Spain in about 1.5 months and I'm looking for games that I can play on my Android device without an active internet connection.

More specifically, I'm looking for a fast-paced game that involves building an empire. I really want it to be fast-paced, because I want to sink my teeth into the game for hours at a time without having hour-long pauses waiting for my construction to finish or my army to return.

Needs:

1. completely playable offline
2. no microtransactions
3. preferably story-driven
4. playable for hours at a time without excessive waiting